# how can i select the active processes on specific activity in camunda

Tags: camunda

... or more specific i want to know

- for each process
- for each process step
- how many processes are on this step
- at the moment and more nice for more than x minutes

The REST interface https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/execution/get-query-count/ gives me the count only for a specific step, not for all. And for processes with many step i dont want to query (feeled) thousand times to get the information.

In the database i tried this, but i gives my redundant not specific active on this step count. But i dont need to rework my queries when something is changing.

```
select job.proc_def_key_, job.act_id_, count(ex.id_)
from camunda.act_ru_jobdef job, camunda.act_ru_execution ex
where job.proc_def_id_ = ex.proc_def_id_
and ex.business_key_ is not null
group by job.proc_def_key_, job.act_id_
order by job.proc_def_key_, job.act_id_
```

Comment: What kind of steps are you interested in (UserTask, ExternalTask...)?

Comment: All of them, at every process step a process can run into an incident or have to wait for an external service or else.